# Creating .exe from c project with built in SDL2 library

Tags: c, sdl-2, static-linking

I've created a SDL2 based project, that after the building proccess creates a prog.exe file.
Sending the project to other systems creates an error: 
`ERROR: The program can't start because SDL2.dll is missing from your computer.` 
Which makes sense, because they didn't install sdl to begin with.
Is there a way for me to send them the .exe file that already has all the needed libraries, without making them to install SDL by themselves?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you might *statically link* the SDL library, so read more about [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)). How to do that is operating system specific (and you don't mention your OS in your question). On Linux you'll link some `libsdl.a` static library

Comment: What compiler? You might get compiler-specific help on static linking if you mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take sdl2.dll from your computer and copy that to the same directory on the other computer as you have the .exe in.

Typically an installer for your application would handle this.

Comment: well that's embarrassing, it's not the classiest solution, but it works and easy, thanks a lot.